# What should questions for the RetrieVe query language be tagged as?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

It appears that the current `retrieve` tag is used for generic retrieval of data on over 300 questions. There is no tag wiki summary for it.

I can't see how it would be helpful to have a generic `retrieve` tag when you could easily search it as a keyword and expect to find related questions. Any domain-specific questions related to retrieval of data would be accompanied by a domain-specific tag or keyword, and generic questions about retrieval should probably be posted on the [Programmers site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) instead. However, trying to search for answers for the actual RetrieVe language is near impossible since many unrelated questions are likely to contain the word "retrieve".

**How should questions for the [RetrieVe](http://www.mannyneira.com/universe/retrieve.html?black) query language be tagged?**

Would it be a good idea to remove the `retrieve` tag from existing posts and create a wiki summary for the RetrieVe language?

Comment: I'm new here, so forgive me if this seems like an extremely stupid question or a bad idea, but I think it would be helpful.

Comment: Are there already questions about RetrieVe on Stack Overflow, or are you asking for potential future questions? (It sounds like the former, but I'd like to confirm.) I did a quick Google search to see if I could find any but, as you remarked, the name makes it difficult to find results. A less ambiguously-named tag is a good idea. *edit:* Yes, there are. [Here's one example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068026/universe-retreive-how-do-i-query-a-file-for-all-of-its-columns-values).

Comment: I've tried to search RetrieVe in the past for help, to no avail. I refrained from posting my question since the tag appeared to be generic. Now that I understand RetrieVe better I was hoping to go answer some questions for people and ran into the same problem.